# GCC for ARM reports warning - potential uninitialized variable

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

This is the code that generates warning: `'res' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`

```c
lwdtcr_t
lwdtc_cron_parse_multi(lwdtc_cron_ctx_t* cron_ctx, const char** cron_strs, size_t ctx_len, size_t* fail_index) {
    lwdtcr_t res;

    ASSERT_PARAM(cron_ctx != NULL);
    ASSERT_PARAM(cron_strs != NULL);
    ASSERT_PARAM(ctx_len > 0);

    /* Parse all input strings, each to its own cron context structure */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ctx_len; ++i) {
        if ((res = lwdtc_cron_parse_with_len(&cron_ctx[i], cron_strs[i], strlen(cron_strs[i]))) != lwdtcOK) {
            if (fail_index != NULL) {
                *fail_index = i;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Assert param macro is defined as

```c
#define ASSERT_PARAM(c)                     if (!(c)) { return lwdtcERRPAR; }
```

```
/* Footprint of function being called inside is */
lwdtcr_t
lwdtc_cron_parse_with_len(lwdtc_cron_ctx_t* ctx, const char* cron_str, size_t cron_str_len)
```

Compiler

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.3.1 20210824 (release)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I am having hard time to understand why this warning? Assert will kick-in in case variable is `0` and return immediately, meaning `for` loop will always execute at least one round - if it gets to that point of course - meaning `res` will be initialized at return statement.

There must be a optimization trick - but I'm not aware of at least - any clue?

`lwdtcr_t` is simple enumeration.

## How to reproduce

Run code from here: https://godbolt.org/z/9E1xdv4dc

Removing '-Og' from flags magically works without any error

## Minimum example

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef enum {
    lwdtcOK = 0x00,                             /*!< Everything is OK */
    lwdtcERR,                                   /*!< Generic error */
    lwdtcERRPAR,                                /*!< Invalid parameter passed to a function */
    lwdtcERRTOKEN,                              /*!< Token value is not valid */
} lwdtcr_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t flags;                             /*!< List of all sort of flags for internal use */
} lwdtc_cron_ctx_t;

lwdtcr_t    lwdtc_cron_parse_with_len(lwdtc_cron_ctx_t* ctx, const char* cron_str, size_t cron_str_len);

#define ASSERT_PARAM(c)                     if (!(c)) { return lwdtcERRPAR; }

lwdtcr_t
lwdtc_cron_parse_multi(lwdtc_cron_ctx_t* cron_ctx, const char** cron_strs, size_t ctx_len) {
    lwdtcr_t res;

    ASSERT_PARAM(cron_ctx != NULL);
    ASSERT_PARAM(cron_strs != NULL);
    ASSERT_PARAM(ctx_len > 0);

    /* Parse all input strings, each to its own cron context structure */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ctx_len; ++i) {
        res = lwdtc_cron_parse_with_len(&cron_ctx[i], cron_strs[i], strlen(cron_strs[i]));
    }
    return res;
}
```

With flags `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -Og`

And compiler

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.3.1 20210824 (release)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: If the loops will not be executed due to their conditions then the variable res will not be initialized.

Comment: That's the point - can it happen loop won't get executed? I cannot find a case right now - but clearly I am wrong somewhere

Comment: The trivial workaround would be to initialize `res` to `lwdtcERRPAR`. After that, it's a trivial transformation to replace the `ASSERT_PARAM` macro's with a single if-statement, which removes the multiple return statements. This helps compilers to understand the possible paths through the function

Comment: Is that the only definition for `ASSERT_PARAM`? No conditional compilation business that replaces it by a no-op?

Comment: Start with a default value such as `lwdtcr_t res = lwdtcOK;` or a fail. Then you are covered.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that's the only one - here the actual code - https://github.com/MaJerle/lwdtc/blob/57705c9b6206642f22be658814b45e16cac9ec3c/lwdtc/src/lwdtc/lwdtc.c#L46 - Starting with default one is indeed a solution - but I am interested if there is my issue or compiler bug

Comment: Macros like `ASSERT_PARAM` are typically conditionally defined, so they are replaced by actual code in debug builds and are replaced by nothing in deployment builds. You should edit the question to provide a [mre], including complete code that others can compile and execute without any changes or additions. You should also state the specific GCC version you are using and the command-line switches used to compile.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's it - no conditional compilation. Code above is reproduceable.

Comment: @tilz0R: You should edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: For example, here is a [mre] that shows [GCC 11.2 does not produce a warning in the situation you describe](https://godbolt.org/z/s1n1aEPj9): `int foo(int ctx_len) { int res; if (! (ctx_len > 0)) return -1; for (int i = 0; i < ctx_len; ++i) res = 3; return res; }`.

Comment: What compiler options have you used?  Cannot reproduce either.  That said, why worry when it is both easier and best practice to simply initialise it.

Comment: Still no MRE from the OP. So I cloned [the project](https://github.com/MaJerle/lwdtc), copied its `lwdtc_opts_template.h` to `lwdtc_opts.h`, edited its `lwdtc.c` file to replace each `#include` of a project header (not standard C library headers) with the contents of that file, recursively, pasted the source into Compiler Explorer, and compiled with GCC 11.2 with `-Wall -Werror`. [There is no warning or error from the compiler.](https://godbolt.org/z/ccY6Th8aj) I request others vote to close this as non-reproducible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as written in q, gcc 10.3.1

Comment: Incorrect "maybe uninitialized" warnings aren't really a bug - or if so, they're a bug that in general can't be fixed.  Because of the halting problem, no compiler can detect uninitialized variables perfectly.  There will always be false positives, or false negatives, or both.

Comment: I narrowed it down. Warning is produced with these flags `-Wall -Wextra -Og`, and is not visible in `-Wall -Wextra` for some reason. Case closed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Q updated with how to reproduce part. You can run this code: https://godbolt.org/z/6r3rb5vrG

Comment: The question should be updated to contain (not merely point to) a [mre], like [this one](https://godbolt.org/z/164cEqcK8). Make the code **minimal**, not a dump from your entire source code. Include the code and the compilation switches in the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you cannot complain anymore... https://godbolt.org/z/9E1xdv4dc

Comment: While this is a known GCC shortcoming (there are duplicates on Stack Overflow; searching for `"-Wmaybe-uninitialized"` reveals several), there may be a fix in this particular case that is preferred to the usual answer of “initialize the variable.” Some people balk at inserting an unnecessary initialization, reasoning that it may add unnecessary execution time and instructions, however slight. And that belief is justified, as the fact the compiler fails to recognize the object is not used uninitialized suggests it will not optimize the initialization…

Comment: … However, in this case, if we do initialize the variable, with `lwdtcr_t res = lwdtcERR;`, and also remove `ASSERT_PARAM(ctx_len > 0);`, then, when the `for` loop falls through because `ctx_len` is not positive, the `return res;` will return the value the `ASSERT_PARAM` macro would return. So the code generated by the compiler may not be any worse with this workaround than it would be with the original code.

Comment: Workaround is clear - I was wondering only if my code can at any optimization level produce undefined behavior tho. THx, case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, in its bare bones (you could have done this simplification yourself before posting):

```
int f (unsigned int len) {
    int res;
    if (len == 0) return 99;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        res = i;
    return res;
}
```

This produces a similar warning.

But if you replace `res = i` with `res = 99`, the warning goes away. So it looks like a case of the compiler just not being infinitely clever. It's not worth spending much time on such cases; the simplest fix is to initialise with `int res = 0;` (with a comment explaining why).

Answer (score -1):

It says ***may be*** used uninitialized.  This means the compiler is not sure.  There is a different warning given where it says ***is*** used uninitialized.

The purpose of the warning is to make you look again at the code and question yourself.  If you have done this and are satisfied that the compiler is wrong in this case, then you can ignore the warning.

If you are not sure, try looking at the disassembly listing of the compiler output.

One thing I would suggest is that the macro `assert` from the standard library sometimes compiles to error checking code and sometimes compiles to nothing depending on the compiler settings.  Using assert as part of your macro name implies similar behaviour, so check your build settings.

Comment: Ignoring the warning is not best advice.  If you do that, and live with a number of warnings in your build, when one you really need to be aware of pops up, you my miss it amongst the noise you have allowed to build up.

Comment: Obfuscating correct code with changes made just to silence mistaken warnings is also a risk.

Comment: In this case, you could easily initialize the variable to suppress this warning, but on another platform with a better compiler you will then get the warning "redundant initializer".

Comment: I have never seen a compiler do that and would not regard that as "better".  Many if not all high-integrity and safety-critical coding standards _require_ initialisation.  An _optimizer_ can safely (and silently)  _remove_ redundant explicit initialisation.  The point is that the initialisation may not remain redundant under code maintenance.